# How to update child gridview label value on change of the parent grid text change event using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one nested grid view control for my requirement. In parent grid there is text with "total value" and in  child grid two columns with "%" and "percentage value". In child grid "%" items are text whereas "Percentage value" is Label. I need to change the value of the "Percentage value" labels when "total value" text field get changed in the parent grid view. Please refer below image for ur reference.

[image]

Thanks,
EN

Comment: To answer this I need .aspx page code in your question.

Comment: Thanks all.. I got solution with below code in jquery.
 $(divname).parent().next('td').next('td').find('span').html(parseFloat((test * totSpend)/100).toFixed(2));

Comment: Could you post your answer in the answer box?